# pip3 fails to install python module with space in name from requirments.txt

Tags: python, pip, jupyter

I would like to install `jupyter qtconsole` from a requirments file using:

```
pip3 install -r requirments.txt
```

When I do, the process halts on `jupyter qtconsole`. It seems that the space in the module name is halting the automated install process, with the result:

```
Invalid requirement: 'jupyter qtconsole'
```

If I type the following into the command prompt, the install works fine.

```
pip3 install jupyter qtconsole
```

I have tried several methods to replace the space in the module name... so far no luck.

Any suggestions?

Strange question to articulate... hard to find similar ones. If this has been asked before please point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyPI packages cannot have spaces in the name. There is no package named `jupyter qtconsole`, and no way to search for one if there were, hence the error.

The reason this line works:

```
pip3 install jupyter qtconsole
```

… is that it's installing two completely separate packages, [`jupyter`](https://pypi.org/project/jupyter/) and [`qtconsole`](https://pypi.org/project/qtconsole/). You can install as many packages as you want in a single `pip install` invocation (and it's often a good idea to do so, so it can work out the dependency graph for all of them at once).

So, just add those two separate packages as requirements to your `requirements.txt` file.

Comment: DUHHHHHHH! Thank you so much!